# Rails - How do I refresh a page without reloading it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, random, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails - How do I refresh a page without reloading it ?

I'm building an app which has a function that gives out a random number (random record) every time people go to that page, but the problem is that when user goes to that page, a random number is given but that number will change again if the user refresh the page.

How do keep that random number even when user refresh the page or comes back to that page, the random number stays the same.

I'm thinking disabling the refresh functionality in browsers which will stop users from refreshing the page hence stop them from changing the random number but after researching, it looks like it is a good idea to disabling the refresh functionality.

Is there any other methods to achieve it?

### ----Update----

I have tried

```
#posts_controller.rb    

def new
       @random = cookies[:stuff] ||= Stuff.random
end
```

and call `@random.content` in my view since I want only the content of the `Stuff` model, the first time is fine but when I refresh the page, it gives me `undefined method 'content' for "#<Stuff:0x0000010331ac00>":String`   What's going on?

Comment: Use cookies to store random number and restore it on page load.

Comment: You can use `session` for this. Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions

Comment: <input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in your controller action:

```
# ex. app/controllers/index_controller.rb
def index
  session[:random] ||= rand(10000)
end
```

This would generate a random number between 0 and 10000 and save it in the user's [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), *only* if it wasn't already present before. This means that it will be the same for each specific user *until* he closes his browser.

If you want persist even after closing the browser then you could use [cookies](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies) instead:

```
cookies[:random] ||= rand(10000)
```

You can replace the `rand(10000)` call by whatever custom method you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but not only will it be random numbers, there will be random letters and words and these random stuff are randomly selected from the database(a model called `Randomstuff`). so `session[:random] ||= rand(10000)` might not work, right?

Comment: The logic is the same, you should just replace `rand(10000)` by a method that will fetch these random stuff, for ex. `random_record()` instead.

Comment: Oh I see, and replace `:random` with the model `:randomstuff` ?

Comment: Btw, am I able to do `@random = cookies[:randomstuff] ||= randomstuff.random` and use `@random` in my view to show the random selected stuff ?

Comment: Hi Agis, I have tried `@random = cookies[:randomstuff] ||= Stuff.random` and call `@random.content` in my view since I want only the content of the `Stuff` model, the first time is fine but when I refresh the page, it gives me `undefined method 'content' for "#<Stuff:0x0000010331ac00>":String`   What's going on?

Comment: Apparently `Stuff.random` returns a string object, on which you are calling the "content" method, which [does not exist for strings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html). Hence the error. Maybe you wanted to just call `@random` since it contains the value?

Comment: but calling `@random` will only return `#<Stuff:0x0000010331ac00>` in my view. The `random` method will select a random record. By the way can you check out [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278753/rails-how-do-i-refresh-a-page-without-reloading-it-updated/22278933?noredirect=1#comment33845179_22278933)  I have open a new question regarding this problem.