# Rails - How do I refresh a page without reloading it? (updated)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4

This question is about problems I ran into after asking my previous question [Rails - How do I refresh a page without reloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144927/rails-how-do-i-refresh-a-page-without-reloading-it)

Have been googling but cannot find a solution.

I'm building a function that gives out a random record every time people go to that page  but the random record will change again if the user refresh the page.

Therefore I have tried using cookies

```
#posts_controller.rb    

def new
  @random = cookies[:stuff] ||= Stuff.random
end
```

and call `@random.content` in my `posts/new` view since I want only the content of the `Stuff` model, when I go to the page for the first time is fine but when I refresh the page, it gives me this error

```
undefined method 'content' for "#<Stuff:0x0000010331ac00>":String
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks!

**----Update----**

I have fixed the `content` missing problem using `<%= show_random(@random)['content'] %>` and the `Internal Server Error expected Hash (got Array) for param 'post'`using

```
<%= f.hidden_field :stuff_id , :value => show_random(@random)[:id] %>
```

**stuff/new.html.erb**

```
# app/views/stuff/new.html.erb

<%= show_random(@random)[:content] %>

      <div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :stuff_id , :value => show_random(@random)[:id] %><br>
      </div>
```

**But when creating the Post without meeting the validation, it gives me**

```
no implicit conversion of Stuff into String

Extracted source (around line #2):

1
2  <%= show_random(@random)['title'] %>
```

I think it has something to do with my create action in my **Posts_controller.erb**

Please have a look below of my **Posts_controller.erb**

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created successfully!"
      else
      @random = Stuff.where(id: params[:post][:stuff_id]).first
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time , as cookies[:stuff] is null, so a new Stuff instance is assigned to both cookies[:stuff] and @random, so the content method call on @random will be fine. But as you store an object into the cookies[:stuff], the value will be converted into a string by rails automatically.

The second time, you visit the page, the cookies[:stuff] is not empty, and is assigned to the @random variable. But as previous saying, the content inside the cookies is a string, so calling content method on a string can not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a way to call the stored cookie as a `model` again in the view so I can call the method `content`? and when users refresh the page the content stays the same until the cookie expire.

Comment: you can just store the content inside the cookie instead of the Stuff instance. Otherwise, you have to do the serialization back and forth by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.random` method defined on `Stuff` return a *serialized* record, which you can then deserialize in your views (possibly with a helper method) to make it a hash:

```
# app/models/stuff.rb
def self.random
  random_record_magic.to_json
end
end

# app/views/stuff/index.html.erb
<%= show_random(@random)['content'] %>

# app/helpers/stuff_helper.rb
def show_random(random)
  JSON.parse(random)
end
```

Comment: Hi Agis. Thanks for the answer, for some reason my view is blank. I have called `<%= show_random(@random)[:content] %>` but the `content` isn't showing.

Comment: I have test it in the rails console, `show_random(@random)[:content]` returns `nil`  What's going on ?   `show_random(@random)` returns  `{"id"=>2, "content"=>"SUP!", "created_at"=>"2014-03-09T03:16:21.501Z", "updated_at"=>"2014-03-09T03:16:21.501Z"}`

Comment: OK updated my code. It should be `show_random(@random)['content']`.

Comment: thanks for the update, do you know what might have caused the `Internal Server Error expected Hash (got Array) for param 'post'` error ?  This happens when I tried to create a post. `<%= show_random(@random)[:content] %>` is in my posts/new.html.erb